# Android + Facebook API - write on Facebook wall with link to another Facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink, facebook-wall

I have a problem with Android Facebook API with writting to wall. I want to write there and add a link to another Facebook page. While other links work, Facebook links do not. Am I doing something wrong?

Normal links work:

```
// ...
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "some message");
parameters.putString("link", "http://root.cz");
mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new WallPostDialogListener());
// ...
```

Facebook links do not work:

```
// ...
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "some message");
parameters.putString("link", "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Juky-MC/170228716347899");
mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new WallPostDialogListener());
// ...
```

I get facebook window with "Sorry, something went wrong." "We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can." error messages. Could anybody help me?

Thanks Jan

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `"www."` at the `"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Juky-MC/170228716347899"` ?

Comment: No, I have not :-) Thanks a lot, it really works without "www.".